# Host drivers are not mounted when ssh into cygwin

Tags: ssh, cygwin, mount

I have installed cygwin64 in a Windows 7 and also configured an ssh server inside Cygwin that automatically starts with the host. On the host, I have 3 local disks, `C:`, `E:` and `Z:` When I open Cygwin through the `cygwin.bat` or through the shortcut, these drivers are available inside cygwin as `/cygdrive/c`, `/cygdrive/e` and `/cygdrive/z`, but if I open through an SSH connection, driver `Z:` is not available. Let me add that driver `Z:` is a folder that the host shared using Vmware shared folder feature. 
I already tried to map using mount `Z:` `<folder_that_exists>`, but it simple returns "mount: Z: Invalid argument". What should I do so when I connect, these drivers are already mapped?

Comment: This problem seems related to https://serverfault.com/questions/211057/access-nfs-share-from-cygwin

Comment: When I execute cygwin locally with "run as administrator", the command "net use" shows the driver as "unavailable". If I run normally, the net use shows the driver as  ok.